# Batch iteration of file list using specific filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, iteration

Hi all i am a noob to programming (in practice) have done some courses though, and i apologise in advance if i am wasting your time with my problem.

I would like to process images using a batch file that i have made already, the problem is i need to process 100+ images using their file name as an input and would like to know how to make this possible?

my script looks like this

```
@echo on
echo file name convention:M02-ASCA-ASCSMR02-NA-3.2-20140129081200.000000000Z-1095218.bfr
echo test from UMARF
echo note orbit number as %9
rem set orbitnumber=%9


set longfilename= %filename% 
rem: shorfilename1=yyyymmdd
set shortfilename1=%longfilename:~26,12%
echo shortfilename1
pause
set PATH=%D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012\Extensions\GEONETCast-Toolbox\util%
call 7z.exe e %longfilename%.bz2
pause
echo on
set PATH=%D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012\Extensions\GEONETCast-Toolbox\util%
pause

rem: Ascat surface soil moisture
rem: in top 5 cm of soil
rem: output point map is estimate of water saturation from 0-100%


set VBUFR_TABLE_DIR=D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012\Extensions\GEONETCast-Toolbox\util\tables
set VBUFR_DATA_DIR=D:\test


call bufrtool.exe pick %longfilename% 6001 5001 40001 40002 40003 40007 > D:\test\%shortfilename1%_org.txt

call deletelines.exe D:\test\%shortfilename1%_org.txt D:\test\%shortfilename1%_imp.txt 7
copy D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012\Extensions\GEONETCast-Toolbox\util\asc.dm# 
copy D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012\Extensions\GEONETCast-Toolbox\util\asc.dom %shortfilename1%.dom

set PATH=%D:\geonetcast\Software\ILWIS\Ilwis372_oct2012%
call ilwis.exe -C D:\test\%shortfilename1%.tbt:=table(D:\test\%shortfilename1%_imp.txt,Space,Convert,none,ID(D:\test\%shortfilename1%.dom{id}),X(value.dom{-180:180:0.00001}),Y(value.dom{-90:90:0.00001}),SM_perc(value.dom{0:100:0.01}),Error_perc(value.dom{0:100:0.01}),Mean_SM(value.dom{0:100:0.0001}),Quality(value.dom{0:100:1}));
call ilwis.exe -C D:\test\%shortfilename1%_smperc.mpp:=PointMapFromTable(D:\test\%shortfilename1%,LatlonWGS84,SM_perc);
rem
```

end

(i know a tad long)- i have searched for a solution i can use but am struggling at present, I found this code on another site but can't get it to work for my itteration,

```
FileList = dir('*.csv');
N = size(FileList,1);

for k = 1:N

   % get the file name:
   filename = FileList(k).name
   disp(filename);

   % insert your script code here
```

would really appreciate some help.

Regards
J-bon3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For %A in (c:\windows\*.ini) do echo %A
```

In a batch file you use %%A rather than %A at a command prompt. See

```
for /?
```

You can also see

```
forfiles /?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of the files in a file. Like this :

FileList.txt :

```
File1.xxx
File2.xxx
File3.xxx
File5.xxx
```

You can use a simple `FOR` loop with a `CALL` to do what you want :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type filelist.txt') do call:Work %%a
Echo Done ...
exit/b

:work
set $file=%1
echo Treating File : [%$file%]
```

Output :

```
Treating File : [File1.xxx]
Treating File : [File2.xxx]
Treating File : [File3.xxx]
Treating File : [File5.xxx]
Done ...
```

Comment: The file is represented in the VAR `%$file%`

Comment: @tony_bd thanks for the assistance it works well, i went with sacha's method it saved me hours of work...